# Serializers Base changed in Jackson 2

Tags: java, jackson

I upgraded the version of jackson from 1.x to 2.x in the sources of my application. Because I am Using **org.codehaus.jackson.map.Serializers.Base**, I was looking for an jackson 2 equivalent. **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.Serializers.Base** seems to be this equivalent, but the method

```
JsonSerializer<?> findSerializer(SerializationConfig config, JavaType type, BeanProperty property)
```

changed to

```
JsonSerializer<?> findSerializer(SerializationConfig config, JavaType type, BeanDescription beanDesc).
```

As you can see, the parameter **BeanProperty property** changed to **BeanDescription beanDesc**. But because of I need the BeanProperty property, I want to convert the BeanDescription somehow.

Does anyone know, how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There two problems here that present an obstacle:

1. `BeanDescription` seems to hold information about all `BeanProperty`-ies of a Java Bean, and I don't see any indication that can point to a single property.
2. A deeper question is what is the purpose of the `BeanDescription` argument (and why do you need its obsolete equivalent) since the purpose of the method is to find a serializer based on the first two arguments.  This is evident from the [javadoc of `Serializers` interface](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/Serializers.html)

> Interface that defines API for simple extensions that can provide
>   additional serializers for various types.

and also the [javadoc of the `findSerializer()` method](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/Serializers.html#findSerializer(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription)):

> Method called by serialization framework first time a serializer is
>   needed for specified type, which is not of a container type (for which
>   other methods are called).

I have a suspicion that if there are several properties of the same type, this method will be called only for the first one, and the same serializer instance will be used for all subsequant same-typed properties.

I took the trouble of looking at the [source of `SimpleSerializers` class](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleSerializers.java) which implements the interface. indeed the body of the abovementioned method makes no use whatsoever of the `BeanDescription` argument

Answer (score 1):

If you need to customise your serialization according to a BeanProperty, you may want to do this by implementing the `ContextualSerializer` interface.

This makes getting the serializer for a property a two-stage affair. The Serializers implementation returns a non-contextual serializer that would be used, for example, when that type was requested as the root type of a serialization. By implementing `ContextualSerializer`, it also functions as a factory for serializers for the same type, but customised according to the bean property being serialized (e.g. the annotations on the property)

This additional stage allows the serializer to use `SerializerProvider` when the bean property is known, not just `SerializationConfig`, so it can fetch other fully-preconfigured serializers to work with, for example.

sth like:

```
class ThingSerializer extends StdSerializer<Thing> implements ContextualSerializer {
    private final JsonFormat.Shape shape;

    public ThingSerializer() {
        this(JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT);
    }

    protected ThingSerializer(JsonFormat.Shape shape) {
        super(Thing.class);
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    @Override
    public ThingSerializer createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty prop) {
        JsonFormat.Value format = prov.getAnnotationIntrospector().findFormat((Annotated)property.getMember());
        // customise implementation if @JsonFormat annotation found
        if (format != null && format.getShape() == JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY) {
            return new ThingSerializer(JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY);
        }
        return this; // just use general implementation
    }

    // use shape member to customise serialization in implemenation...
}
```

(Or this could in fact return a different serializer implementation, rather than just customising it like this)

Note that `createContextual` should not mutate the serializer it is called on, it should create a new one (the clue is in the name). Although just returning `this` if there is no customisation to do is fine.